# I/O Character stream: BufferedReader vs printWriter construction

Tags: java

Why is `BufferedReader` created as such

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
```

while `PrintWriter` can be simply constructed like these

```
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
```

`BufferedReader` can't be constructed directly from `System.in` so it requires `InputStreamReader` to convert bytes to char, is this to make it human readable? But `PrintWriter` dosen't require a wrap from char back to bytes why is that so, does Java automate it? Because to a machine everything is 1 & 0 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> so it requires InputStreamReader to convert bytes to char, is this to
>   make it human readable?

No, it's for performance. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376647/what-is-the-difference-between-javas-bufferedreader-and-inputstreamreader-class) to see the difference between them.

And there are `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedReader`, they have similar functions and constructors.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
- Binary data: `byte[], InputStream, OutputStream`;
- (Unicode) text: `String, char, Reader, Writer`;
- Bridges where binary data has some encoding/Charset and is actually text: `InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter` (converting from/to given or default Charset).

Now consider:

- `System.in` is a `InputStream`.
- `System.out` and `System.err` are a `PrintStream` extending from `OutputStream`.

They are conceived as for binary data, which for Unix is quite normal and useful. For a console however not so useful. However `PrintStream` might be a design mishap/error: it has text support, also for passing a Charset; it is a half OutputStreamWriter.

> So see **`PrintStream`** as an old unclean class doing what an `OutputStreamWriter + BufferedWriter` does, however not being a `Writer`.

`BufferedWriter+OutputStreamWriter` has the same complexity (though being reversed) as `PrintStream`. One also sees **Scanner**: `new Scanner(System.in)`. This is not a `Reader`, and has superfluous support for tokenizing. It like `PrintStream` has the advantage of briefness, but is definitely more unclean for its unneeded overhead. (There are quite a lot of bugs mentioned in StackOverflow on Scanner.)